# Rails Polymorphism for User modeling

Tags: authentication, devise, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I'm new to Rails 5 and I'm trying to model the following scenario using Devise and CanCanCan: a store application.
Relevant figures are: Admin, StoreManager, StoreOfficer, Customer, Technician.

- Admin creates StoreManager.
- StoreOfficer can create Customer's information to register new Customers.
- StoreOfficer can see the complete list of all Customers with relative information
- StoreOfficer can see the complete list of all Technicians with relative information
- StoreManager can see the complete list of all StoreOfficers with relative information
- StoreManager can enable StoreOfficers to use the system and edit their information
- StoreManager can enable Customers created by StoreOfficers to use the system
- StoreManager can see the complete list of all Customers with relative information

There are also some other paths, but it's possible for me to develop them as these presented cases are done.

Any help/tutorial please?

Thanks,
FZ

Comment: You would get a quicker response if you show what have you accomplished so far following the documentation of `rails`, `devise` and `cancancan`. And explaining where exactly you got stuck including the code examples and the relevant error information.

Comment: How can I post some code example if I still have to understand what approach is better to develop such a schema? I have the following facts:

1- admin manages everything and have a progressiveid, lastname, secondname and sex as fields.
2- StoreManagers have the same fields as admins, StoreOfficers have the same fields as admin plus a reference to the id of his boss who is a StoreManager.
3- Customers have the same fields as admins plus a reference to the id of the StoreOfficer who registered him.
4- Customers don't login in the system, but are registered by a specific StoreOfficer.

Comment: Said that, should I use STI or polymorphic associations? Do devise/cancancan interfere with STI or polymorphic associations?
Do I apply command `rails generate devise User` to class User or maybe i have to create one different class for each user role i need (class Admin, class StoreOfficer, class StoreManager)?

Answer (score 0):

After trying some different things, I created the following satisfying schema, which I post here for others so that they can use something solid:

```
Class User<ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Then all the other roles classes similar to the following one:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :technician
    belongs_to :store_officer

    has_one :user, as: :userable, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :address
end
```

Accordingly, I created all the needed fields using migrations in the database.
Then I put in every controller the code `before_action :authenticate_user!`.

After populating the db a bit, I can now login with different users inserted using rake db:seed.

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    resources :store_managers
    resources :store_officers
    resources :items
    resources :technicians
    resources :customers
    resources :addresses
    resources :users
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see     http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

What do you all think about this setup?
Now I want to introduce CanCanCan to my project. Please validate the following steps I'm going to do:

1. Run `rails g cancan:ability`
2. Put all the rules in the ability.rb file:

   ```
   if user.admin?
     can :manage, :all
   elsif user.store_manager?
     can :read, Customer
     can :create, Customer
     can :update, Item do |item|
       item.try(:user) == user
     end
     can :destroy, Item do |item|
       item.try(:user) == user
     end
   elsif user.store_officer?
     can :read, Customer
   end
   .
   .
   .
   ```
3. Create the methods in user.rb model to check roles:

   ```
   def customer?
     self.userable_type == Customer
   end
   ```
4. Put `load_and_authorize_resource` in every controller

Do you think this approach is the correct one? Or maybe I should put methods/definitions in other files?

Thanks,
FZ